# batch rename for pictures without changing original name in windows 8

Tags: windows-8, batch

**hi**

a friend has given me a wonderful small program to rename my pictures (batch rename). it is much easier than all the other programmes I have found so long and I'm really fond of it. The only problem is that since I have changed my computer and I'm using windows 8 I can not use the programme any longer. He has given me the code. it looks like this:

```
GroupAdd, Explorer, ahk_class ExploreWClass
GroupAdd, Explorer, ahk_class CabinetWClass

#IfWinActive, ahk_group Explorer
^j::
Paths =
for Window in ComObjCreate("Shell.Application").Windows
Selected := Window.Document.SelectedItems
for item in Selected
Paths .= item.path "`n"
InputBox,Suffix, `n Massrenamer for files and thumbnails by CASABIO.org, (Select a file or multiple files in Windows Explorer and press Ctrl + J 
Type in the  word to be appended to the file name
If nothing happens, try re-opening explorer)
If ErrorLevel != 0
Return
Loop,Parse,Paths,`n
{
If A_LoopField =
Break
SplitPath,A_LoopField,,Dir,Ext,Name
FileMove,%A_LoopField%,% Dir "\" Name " " Suffix "." Ext,1
}
Return
```

I don't understand a thing here, but maybe someone can tell me how I could change the thing so that it runs in windows 8

many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is an [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script. You have two choices to get this to run:

1. Install AutoHotKey on your machine
2. Ask your friend to compile this script into a stand-alone executable so that you can run it without AutoHotKey.

I recommend option 2 because it is simpler and safer for you.

AutoHotKey is great for running macros and remapping keys if you use it and know what you are doing, but it also opens you up to attack by malicious scripts that otherwise wouldn't run on your machine.